# How is the second part of a dual number called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, notation

A complex number $a + bi$ has a *real* part $a$ and an *imaginary* part $b$.

But, what about [dual numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) $u + v\epsilon $? I have [seen](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/637789/15863) the non-real part $v$ been called
the *infinitesimal* part. Is this a common convention? Or is there a different one?

Comment: I've never heard a common name, and a truly common name should appear in Wikipedia. "Infinitesimal part" is pretty good, or "nonconstant part" in a pinch.

Comment: In some sources I have seen also imaginary part.